# Adding css to a class not existing yet

Tags: javascript

hey there is a way to add a class in javascript to a element not activated yet ? I used

```
$( ".myelement ).attr('class', 'myelement toast');
```

myelement dont appear in my code, so the class is not applied until i launched it once ?

Comment: *not activated yet* - hidden or non-existent?

Comment: Where is element added to `document`?

Comment: dont appear until I use the module who add new code !

Comment: _"so the class is not applied until i launched it once"_ What is issue with that approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this :

```js
let exist = false;
document.body.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { 
// http://caniuse.com/#search=DOMSubtreeModified

  // warning : this will run everytime the dom modified
  // this check will prevent unwanted loops
  if(!exist) {
    setTimeout( function() {
      const theDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
      if(theDiv && !exist) {
        exist = true;
        console.log("It is right there, let's add a class to it");
        
        // add some delay (not a must, just to follow easily)
        setTimeout( function() {
          theDiv.setAttribute('class', theDiv.getAttribute('class')+' cool');
          console.log('done!')
        },1000);
      }
    },0);
  }
});

console.log("Waiting 2 seconds...");

// delay to follow things easily
setTimeout( function() {
  console.log("Creating a div..");
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.innerHTML = 'Cool!';
  newDiv.setAttribute('id','theDiv');
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  console.log("Created.");
},2000);
```

```css
.cool {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely right: you will not be able to add an attribute, data, properties, etc... to elements that are not yet in the DOM.

You will need to do that call every time a ".myelement" node is created and added to the page.

By the way, for css classes, don[t use "attr" - use [jQuery's class methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) instead.

Hope this helps!